# apprtc - getusermedia() failed

Tags: python, webrtc, getusermedia

i downloaded apprtc from [here](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/#svn/trunk/samples/js/apprtc). Then i installed python 2.7, the google-appengine-api and all dependencies. i add all to my path and run the following command:

```
dev_appserver.py apprtc
```

which produce the following output:

```
INFO     2014-04-24 21:31:34,246 sdk_update_checker.py:242] Checking for updates
to the SDK.
INFO     2014-04-24 21:31:35,681 sdk_update_checker.py:286] This SDK release is
newer than the advertised release.
INFO     2014-04-24 21:31:35,917 api_server.py:171] Starting API server at: http
://localhost:46857
INFO     2014-04-24 21:31:35,924 dispatcher.py:182] Starting module "default" ru
nning at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2014-04-24 21:31:35,927 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at:
http://localhost:8000
```

but if i now open localhost:8080 in chrome or firefox there popup the following message:

```
getusermedia() failed. is this a webrtc capable browser

Gathered ICE Candidates
Local:
Remote:
getUserMedia failed with exception: getUserMedia is not defined
```

but if i open [the official apprtc demo](https://apprtc.appspot.com/) it's running fine.

what can be the reason for the failures i get local?
thank you!

Comment: 1. What browser are you using? Make sure you use latest browsers.
2. Enable flags in chrome://flags (This may not be applicable for every version)
3. In firefox, you cannot use camera in two tabs, make sure you close the apprtc tab and then try your code

Comment: 4. Check if you are using correct vendor prefixes too.

Comment: How are you accessing `adapter.js`? I am guessing that the shims are now inaccessible. Download, [adapter.js](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/samples/js/base/adapter.js) and add it to your page.

Answer (score 2):

try this to getuser media

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
```